# Disabling ajax on HTTP 302 in jQueryMobile

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, silex, http-status-code-302

In jQueryMobile, is there a way to disable ajax pages loading when the server respond HTTP 302 ?

I have a login page (`mydomain.tld/login`) with specific javascript library on this page (and only on this page). When a user is logged in, and session expire, the user is redirected by the Silex framework to the login page when he try to access new content (`mydomain.tld/mycontent` --> `mydomain.tld/login`). Normal.

Problem : loading of the login page failed because jQueryMobile try to load this page with ajax, so the specific JS library for the login page is not loaded (jQueryMobile insert only page content into the DOM) and so the login page failed to initialize without this library...

I don't wan't to load this specific library on all pages for efficiency reasons (this library is usefull on login, useless on all the rest of the site).

I don't really want to disable ajax loading of pages for all the site...

Is there a way to disable ajax loading only when the server respond a HTTP 302 or disable ajax for a specific page (param in mobileinit ?)

Thank in advance for your ideas and suggestions...

Comment: Can't you force the [load of the login library with AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) also?

Comment: I finally opt for loading a light-weight version of the library on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

or you can disable request before the route :

```
$app->before(function(Request $request, Application $app)) {
   if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->headers->get('User-Agent') == 'mobile header') {
     return $app->json(array('error' => 'Authentication failed'));
   }
});
```